# Multiplication group of integers modulo

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to show that $ U(3^{n})= \langle [2] \rangle $  for all natural number. I think 1st I have to find out the order of  $[2]$ in $ U(3^{n})$ and then find the size of $ U(3^{n})$.  But i can't do, please someone help me.

Comment: $ [2] $ will not even be in the multiplicative group if $ n $ is even, and even if it is, it might not generate the entire group. Did you mean to say $ 3^n $ and not $ 3n $?

Comment: yes, my mistake

Comment: Do you see how it suffices to show that $ 2^{2 \cdot 3^n} \neq 1 \pmod{3^{n+2}} $? (Use induction on $ n $ to get the claim from this.)

Comment: can you respond to proof , please